# Extensible \rightrightharpoons and \leftleftharpoons

Tags: arrows, mathtools, mathabx

How to achieve extensible double-harpoons in the style of the `\xleftrightharpoons` family of arrows from `mathtools`, but with both harpoons pointing in the same direction?

[image]

Preferably without Tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? A quick and dirty method...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\xrightharpoonupdown}[2][-12pt]{%
\stackunder[#1]{$\xrightharpoonup{\text{#2}}$}{$\xrightharpoondown{\text{\phantom{#2}}}$}%
}%


\begin{document}


\xrightharpoonupdown{but with longer harpoons}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

Give the text to be `harpooned` as 2nd argument, in the first optional you can reduce the vertical spacing between the up and the down harpoon. If  omitted, a default value of `-10pt` is used. This could be changed in command definition or when appropiate during usage of the command.

Comment: Ok, that's plausible solution (hadn't thought of using `\phantom` to hack two extensible harpoons to be of the same length). I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should change to `-12pt` also, it gives a better impression, in my point of view, the `-10pt` just were a first guess ;-)