# One way implication, one way no implication

Tags: amsmath, arrows

I would like to make 2 implication arrows on top of one another, facing opposite directions, such that the bottom one is actually a not implies. I would also like to be able to label these arrows with text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Should these arrows be extensible in function of the text?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180411/121799) and see if you can modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Does that answer me as described in your question? There are three types of examples, with the hope that I have answered correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[a\mkern10mu\Rightarrow \mkern-30mu\nLeftarrow\mkern10mu b\]
\[a \nLeftrightarrow b\]
\[a \overset{\,\scaleobj{1.5}{\Rightarrow}}{\nLeftarrow} b\]
\end{document}
```